# RSpec: Test a create action method in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

I have write a RSpec Test for a create action method in a controller. Now i became the following error:
[error Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a8eX9.png)

My Test:

```
describe '#create' do
before(:each) {
  @address = {
    attributes: {
      'street': "bla",
      'street-number': 2,
      'zip': "12345",
      'city': "blabla",
      'country': ''
    },
    type: "addresses"
  }
}


it 'test the create route' do
  post 'create', { params: @address }
end
end
```

My Controller Method:

```
public def create
  action(Address::Create)
    .otherwise('address_create_error', 401)
    .then_render(Address::Representer::Out::Default)
end
```

And my Factory:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :address do
    street 'Musterstraße'
    street_number '1'
    zip '12345'
    city 'Musterstadt'
    country ''
  end
end
```

I have no Idea why this error comes. Could anybody help me?

Comment: What's in Address::Representer::Out::Default and Address::Create? Why are you defining the factory for address but not using it? You should paste the full error message, and definitely NOT a screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved the problem today. To solve it, I had to adjust two things.

1. the JSON must be transferred completely as a string
2. it must be sent in the body of the request, not as a param. That's because of our special environment.

Thanks for your help anyway. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using the "=>" syntax

```
 @address = {
    'attributes' => {
      'street' => "bla",
      'street-number' => 2,
      'zip' => "12345",
      'city' => "blabla",
      'country': ''
    },
    'type' => "addresses"
  }
```